# GWT HTTP Post Testing Using Postman

Tags: java, http, gwt

Anyway to use Postman to test HTTP Post on GWT ?

HTTP POST URL example as below

```
http://localhost:8080/x/rpc
```

Request Payload

```
7|0|4|http://localhost:8080/xxx.admin/admin/|FACC699CEECDE8714C2C622F39051260|com.x.portal.shared.xRpc|getx|1|2|3|4|0
```

I got this error
Content-Type was 'text/plain'. Expected 'text/x-gwt-rpc'.

On Postman, it seem doesn not have a features to set the MIME type to text/x-gwt-rpc

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

on the headers tab. Set the below then it works like a charm

```
Key --> Content-Type

value --> text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
```